# MySQL MATCH-AGAINST scenario

Tags: mysql

I would like someone to help my with this scenario:
I have a table that contains entries. I want to perform a query and get the record with the highest score based on a pattern.
The pattern will be: if my word appears as is then the score will be the highest for that entry. If that word appears as is inside a sentence then the score of that entry will be lower than the previous case.

e.g:
entries
entry1: apple
entry2: one apple per day

if I search for "apple" I would like the entry1 to have higher score than entry2.

So I made this query:

```
SELECT 
 entry,
MATCH
 (entry) 
AGAINST
 ('>("apple") <(apple*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS 
 Score 
FROM 
 entries 
WHERE 
MATCH
 (entry) 
AGAINST 
 ('>("apple") <(apple*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
LIMIT 1
```

But it is wrong. This query returns the same score for the two sentences("apple" and "one apple per day"), because the word "apple" appears as is in both of them.
Any suggestions on what will be the pattern of AGAINST()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    entry,
    MATCH (entry) AGAINST ('>("apple") <(apple*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score
FROM entries 
WHERE MATCH (entry) AGAINST ('>("apple") <(apple*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY LENGTH(entry)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is a very good approach that works on my scenario! But is there any way to actually achieve different scores based on the pattern that I mention?

Comment: I don't see any way to do that. Unless there is some way to divide the Score by the entry length. I think the best you can do is order by length(entry) ASC, Score DESC.